# How to automaticaly update windows service credentials

Tags: .net, windows, service

I install a Windows Service as local or domain user (the user is added to Logon as a service group). Is it possible to automatically update the service account password after changed password of user account?

Comment: You mean, if the user account password changes for *any* reason?  No.  But have you considered using virtual service accounts, or managed service accounts?  Virtual service accounts don't have passwords, and managed service accounts do password rotation automatically.

Comment: ... on second thoughts, for a domain account it would in principle be possible to install a password filter on the domain controllers and have it update the service configuration.  I'm not sure that would be a very sensible solution, but from a technical standpoint it should work.  I forget whether or not you can install a password filter for local accounts.